# CMake multiple calls to project()

Tags: cmake

What are the implications of / possible reasons for calling `project()` from subdirectories' `CMakeLists`?

i.e.

```
├── CMakeLists.txt     <-- top-level project() call
├── proj1
|  ├── CMakeLists.txt  <-- project()
├── proj2
|  └── CMakeLists.txt  <-- project()
└── proj3
   └── CMakeLists.txt  <-- project()
```

I have seen this in codebases before, usually after a refactor.

Is this ever useful? Couldn't you just define targets with `add_library`/`add_executable` instead?

Is this actually harmful, or innocuous?

The [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) only really talk about the special case of the top-level `project()` call, but don't get into reasons for calling it in subdirectories.

Answer (score 3):

The benefit of doing this is that you could use one of your subprojects on its own or use it as part of some other project that does not require its siblings.

There should be no issue with doing this without the parent dir. Afaik there is no issue with this. In fact [the documentation of `PROJECT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_NAME.html) states that there could be multiple `project` commands in use:

> [...]
>
> This is the name given to the most recently called `project(`) command in the current directory scope or above. To obtain the name of the top level project, see the `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME` variable.

I work on a software package that contains > 10 `project` commands and there never was an issue with that.

The visual studio generator creates one solution file per `project()` though but a unnecessary files in the build directory shouldn't be an issue.